# ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="ddlBrokers" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="srcBrokers" 
    DataTextField="broker" 
    DataValueField="brokerId"
/>

<asp:ObjectDataSource
    id="srcBrokers" 
    TypeName="DatabaseComponent.DBUtil" 
    SelectMethod="GetBrokers" 
    runat="server">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

My DAL code:

```
public DataTable GetBrokers(bool? hasImport=null)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetBrokers");
    if (hasImport.HasValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasImport", hasImport);
    return FillDataTable(cmd, "brokers");
}
```

When the form loads I get this error:

```
ObjectDataSource 'srcBrokers' could not find a non-generic method 'GetBrokers' that has no parameters.
```

Is it my optional parameter that is causing the problem? How can I workaround this? Is it possible to have optional parameters with declarative ASP.NET code?

Comment: add methods public DataTable GetBrokers()
{
    return GetBrokers(null);
} and check is it works?

Comment: @galimy: that worked great! Maybe send this comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add method:

```
public DataTable GetBrokers() { 
              return GetBrokers(null);
}
```

and check is it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectParameters` like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource id="srcBrokers" TypeName="DatabaseComponent.DBUtil" SelectMethod="GetBrokers" runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="hasImport" Type="Empty" />
    <SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```