# Issue on ObjectDataSource for Optional parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="BARS.BL.Plant"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Error:** 
*ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'GetAll' that has no parameters*

If I tried to add optional parameter to GetAll method so I got the above error.
How do I resolve it?

Comment: I think you should try [adding a SelectParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to the objectdatasource and be sure to handle a null value or provide a default.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `GetAll` method with optional parameter like this:

```cs
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public DataTable GetAll(int? optionalParam = null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Then you can either create a new method without any parameters that calls overloaded version with null argument:

```cs
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public DataTable GetAll()
{
    return GetAll(null);
}
```

Or create a `SelectParameter` like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                      SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="BARS.BL.Plant">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="optionalParam" Type="Empty" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Similar issues:

[ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490826/objectdatasource-could-not-find-a-non-generic-method)

[Error ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193448/error-objectdatasource-could-not-find-a-non-generic-method)